# Detail cell remains fixed during horizontal scrolling AG-Grid

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

If I scroll the grid screen horizontally, then the column header and row information moves, but not the expanded details section which seems frozen/pinned in place. See the GIF below, for exact description. The section scrolls vertically and moves with the master row like how you'd expect.

[GIF demonstration of scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yByO.gif)

What are some suggested changes?
Thanks all.